# Python mysql-connector multi insert not working?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I just started using the Mysql Connector library for Python and I seem to be running into an issue I can't get my head around.

I have Python dynamically generate Insert statements to be executed on MySQl database.

I batch them together in one string and then I execute every n together in the one `cusrsor.execute()` statement however for some reason when I check the DB and table, the new rows are nowhere to be found.

I tried it with even just two insert statements together and they still didn't get persisted to the DB even though I call execute, call a commit and then close the cursor and connection in that order.

If I have just one insert statement in the execute command and I remove the multi flag then it works fine.

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Sample code:

```
from mysql import connector
my_sql_connection = connector.connect(user='user', password='pass',
                                              host='hostname',
                                              database='db')
mysql_cursor = my_sql_connection.cursor()

statement = "Insert into table (col) values (1); Insert into table (col) values (2);"

mysql_cursor.execute(statement, multi=True)
my_sql_connection.commit()
mysql_cursor.close()
my_sql_connection.close()
```

After this code is called, there are no errors however no new rows show up in the table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try using [executemany](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) instead of `execute` with the multi flag, it's generally much simpler to implement.

Also,I would recommend you switch to [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL), it has a very complete documentation and from my experience works much better 'out of the box' than the mysql connector library.

Comment: I used to use PyMSSQl to connect to our legacy SQL Server DB however it was very poorly written as the cursor would load the entire result set of the select query into memory even if you used the fetchmany(n) command. Do you know if PyMySQL is similar or is it smarter with how it fetches? 

Thanks

Comment: @Mo. I haven't looked extensively at the workings of PyMySQL, but I have used it to deal with fairly sized DBs (~400k rows) with zero issues whatsoever, that's why I usually recommend it. Before it I had tried MySQL connector, OurSQL and some others, but all were a pain to use and straight out unpractical.